# @PostConstruct annotation in java 8 jar not being called by spring boot 3 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-3, spring-boot-2

I have a spring boot version 3.1.4 application running with java 17

This application has a dependency in its pom.xml which is an application written in java 8

The java 8 dependency application uses the PostConstruct annotation from below import

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

The problem is my spring boot 3 application running in java 17 never executes the function marked with @PostConstruct in the dependency.

This issue does not occur when I downgrade my application from spring boot 3 to spring boot 2 and run it using java 17

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you referencing the class containing the @PostConstruct not being called? If you do "new Whatever()", then PostConstruct will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because in spring boot 3 moved from javax to jarkarta. This would mean that you would have to use

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct instead of
javax.annotation.PostConstruct

You might have to get the updated version of the dependency that is compatible with spring boot 3 and java 17

You can take a look at this

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x